# maven-jaxb2-plugin - ignore ssl error

Tags: web-services, maven, ssl, ssl-certificate, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am using maven-jaxb2-plugin and I get the following error

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
```

I understand the certificate expired and I do not manage the webservice. So how do I ignore the SSL error.

I try to generate-source  as

```
generate-sources -Dmaven.wagon.provider.http=httpclient -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true
```

But I still get the same error. How do I configure Maven to ignore SSL error and generate sources.

Answer (score 0):

I stronly advise against compiling online resources.

Create a local copy of what you're compiling and [use catalogs](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-Catalogs) to rewrite URLs.

```
<configuration>
    <catalogs>
        <catalog>
            <dependencyResource>
                <groupId>com.acme.foo</groupId>
                <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
                <!--
                    Version can be omitted if artifact is already
                    configured in dependencies or dependency management.
                -->
                <version><!-- Version --></version>
                <resource>catalog.cat</resource>
            </dependencyResource>
        </catalog>
    </catalogs>
</configuration>
```

Catalog file is as simple as:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org" "w3c"
```